# mysql query repeating data with join

Tags: mysql, sql, join

This is my query.

```
 SELECT dr_trans_dtl.dr_ID, jo_trans_dtl.qty 
 FROM dr_trans_dtl 
 LEFT JOIN jo_trans_dtl ON dr_trans_dtl.jo_no = jo_trans_dtl.jo_no 
 WHERE dr_trans_dtl.dr_no = '3329' GROUP BY dr_trans_dtl.dr_ID
```

Here is the actual result:

[image]

What I wanted is the qty should be like this (500,40,1). Because that is the data in jo_trans_dtl.

Comment: GROUP BY could be `GROUP BY dr_trans_dtl.dr_ID,jo_trans_dtl.qty`

Comment: The result repeats two field/column (dr_ID,qty)

Comment: Give your expected output and give your current data that you are get.

Comment: Without seeing any sample data it's hard to be sure but you could probably remove the `GROUP BY dr_trans_dtl.dr_ID` and change `SELECT dr_trans_dtl.dr_ID, jo_trans_dtl.qty` to `SELECT DISTINCT dr_trans_dtl.dr_ID, jo_trans_dtl.qty`

Comment: Please see pic
https://imgur.com/a/vNsW6NM

Comment: What is `(500,40,1)`? You do not have 40 and 1 in given data so What we can predict them?

Comment: My bad. Its 500,8 and 1

Comment: Still I do not clear what exact your problem is and what you want? can you describe in your question with sample data?

Comment: The actual result was already in my question. I added there a pic. As you can see there, the qty repeats 500. it should be 500,8,1.

Comment: Quantity repeating with different `dr_ID` so is ok or not?

Comment: It's not. What I want to get is 500,8,1.

Comment: Try this one `SELECT DISTINCT  jo_trans_dtl.qty, dr_trans_dtl.dr_ID`

Comment: This is the result
https://imgur.com/a/kfF8P7E

Comment: Have you try above `DISTINCT` query with `GROUP BY dr_trans_dtl.dr_ID`

Comment: Yes my friend..

Comment: If you can create http://sqlfiddle.com/  for your sample data then it is easy to me for understanding

Comment: I think you do not applied `GROUP BY` because in your given screenshot `dr_ID` is repeated which is wrong.

Comment: This is the result with group by dr_ID
https://imgur.com/a/kfF8P7E

Comment: If you applied `GROUP BY` clause on `dr_ID` then this is not right result. So may be you are doing something wrong.

Comment: Give me fiddle with sample data so I can you help further other wise Good Bye.

Comment: This is now my query

SELECT DISTINCT jo_trans_dtl.qty, dr_trans_dtl.dr_ID
FROM dr_trans_dtl 
      LEFT JOIN jo_trans_dtl ON dr_trans_dtl.jo_no = jo_trans_dtl.jo_no 
      WHERE dr_trans_dtl.dr_no = '3329'
      GROUP BY dr_trans_dtl.dr_ID

Answer (score 1):

It seems you need aggregate function as you used group by

```
 SELECT dr_trans_dtl.dr_ID,sum(jo_trans_dtl.qty) as qty
 FROM dr_trans_dtl 
 JOIN jo_trans_dtl ON dr_trans_dtl.jo_no = jo_trans_dtl.jo_no 
 WHERE dr_trans_dtl.dr_no = '3329'
 GROUP BY dr_trans_dtl.dr_ID
```

Comment: The result is
dr_ID   |   qty
9074    |    509
9075    |    509
9076    |    509

It should be
dr_ID   |   qty
9074    |    500
9075    |    40
9076    |    1

Because (500,40,1) are in the jo_trans_dtl.

Comment: @Jonathan share your both table data